# Uniformly equicontinuous sequence of functions that does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

In a past exam of a course I am taking this semester there is the following question for which I can't find any example by myself. The question is to find an uniformly equicontinuous sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous and bounded functions on $[0,1]$ with real values from which we cannot extract a subsequence that converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

If any of you had some examples of such sequences I would be really grateful, I just cannot think of one..

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! For your future questions, please write what your thoughts are so far - what have you tried, what is the context, have you seen a similar problem before etc..

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do so for sure for my future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Arzela-Ascoli, a uniformly bounded, uniformly equicontinuous family of functions on $[0,1]$ always has a uniformly converging subsequence. So one of these assumptions must be violated, and it cannot be the one about equicontinuity.

Consider the sequence $f_n(x) = n$. The functions in this family are uniformly equicontinuous but not uniformly bounded. There is no uniformly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!